# Alineación de etiquetas <p> dentro de un <td>

Tags: html, css

Que tal gente estoy generando los formatos de unos comprobantes, mi resultado esperado es el siguiente, cabe destacar que despues de generar esta plantilla la mando a mpdf para que se generen los repor5es en PDF, solo que necesito que las alineaciones de lo que muestro a continuacion coincidan de la mejor manera posible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he logrado es lo que muestro a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna manera de que con CSS puede alinear de la manera más fiel posible a la imagen 1, el código que he trabajado es el siguiente

```html
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" width="1000" height="200"><img src="img/iconos/escudo_comprobantes.png" alt=""></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="cabecera" width="1000" height="50">COMPROBANTE DE PERCEPCIONES Y DEDUCCIONES &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Recibo: 317860</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="informacion" valign="top" height="100" width="500">
      <strong>Nombre: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br>
      <strong>CURP: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
      <strong>Puesto: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br>
      <strong>Dependencia: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxx <br>
      <strong>Unidad Admva: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
    </td>

    <td colspan="3" class="informacion" valign="top" height="100" width="500">
      <strong>RFC: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxx<br>
      <strong>Clave de ISSEMYM: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxx<br>
      <strong>Fecha de pago: &nbsp;</strong>31/10/2022 <br>
      <strong>Periodo de pago: &nbsp;</strong>16/10/2022 al 31/10/2022 <br>
      <strong>Código de Unidad Administrativa: &nbsp;</strong>22600005L <br>
      <strong>Total neto: &nbsp;</strong>1,520.69 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="cabeceras_perded"><strong>Percepciones</strong></td>
    <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="cabeceras_perded"><strong>Deducciones</strong></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Clave</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Concepto</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Importe</td>

    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Clave</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Concepto</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Importe</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <!--
        <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="consultaperded" valign="top">
            0202 SUELDOS EVENTUALES (7)1,740.00 <br>
            0325 SUBSIDIO AL EMPLEO 99.46 <br> <br>
            <img class="escudoagua" src="img/iconos/escudo_armas.png" width="500" height="450">
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="consultaperded" valign="top">
            5540 SERVICIOS DE SALUD 4.625% 121.59 <br>
            5541 SISTEMA SOLIDARIO DE REPARTO 6.1% 160.37 <br>
            5542 CAPITALIZACION INDIVIDUAL 1.4% 36.81 <br>
            <img class="escudoagua" src="img/iconos/escudo_armas.png" width="500" height="450">
        </td>-->

    <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="consultaclave" valign="top">
      <p style="text-align: center;">0202</p>

    </td>


    <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="consultaconcepto" valign="top">5540 &nbsp;&nbsp; SERVICIOS DE SALUD 4.625% 121.59</td>




  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="totales">Total de percepciones: 1,839.46</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="totales">Total de deducciones: 318.77
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <br> SE REALIZÓ EL ABONO EN LA CUENTA Num.: xxxxxxxxxxx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; EL DÍA: 31/10/2022
      <br><br><br> CONSTITUYE EL RECIBO DE PAGO CORRESPONDIENTE. <br><br><br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Y de CSS hice esto para eliminar el salto de línea automático de la etiqueta

```
p {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yo de ti mostraria todo el HTML en la pregunta, pues veo que usas bootstrap, y creo que te has hecho un poco de lio y que se puede arreglar de forma global partiendo desde la definición de las cabeceras de la tabla, que no aparecen en la pregunta. Y todo con bootstrap y nada de CSS, y menos eso que has puesto, que puede perjudicarte colateralmente en muchos otros sitios.

Comment: Hola no he utilizado Bootstrap todo es CSS y HTML

Comment: Ah, perdon, me confundi el colspan="3" con la clase "col-3"

Comment: Si el colspan es para que ocupe 3 "Espacios"

Comment: Da igual, pon el HTML desde que empiezas con el encabezado de la tabla, donde se vean las columnas Clave, Concepto e Importe

Comment: Claro edito la pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140839/discussion-between-luis-jair-juarez-sanchez-and-masterguru).

Comment: ¿Tiene 6 columnas? ¿Y las repites? Eso no es tampoco toda la tabla... es decir, vale, ahora veo la supuesta cabecera (que por cierto, deberia ir en <th> y no en <td>, y estar en el <thead></thead>... por eso te digo que la pongas toda completa, pues parece más bien un error al formar la tabla que no de CSS.

Comment: Listo, ahora si ya esta todo el table

Comment: Pues no veo el inicio de la misma: <table>, ni el final </table> :-S... perdón, sí, estaban escondidos...

Comment: Vale, entiendo... lo que vamos a hacer es poner tablas dentro de tablas mejor

Comment: Es una sola celda donde esta ese texto? eso parece y si lo divides en 3 celdas?

Comment: Si pensé en dividirlo en 3 celdas, pero después de eso efectuare consulta en SQL y siento que mis datos se van a desbordar

Comment: Debes respetar las celdas y con eso lograras formatear a tu gusto, si es mediante una consulta no creo que tengas problema, ya que en cada celda especificarías el dato a imprimir.

Comment: A ver, esta hecho unos zorros esa tabla... estás usando elementos estructurales (el HTML debe usarse solo para montar la estructura) para intentar modificar elementos de diseño (que deben hacerse con CSS). Te sobran muchos atributos HTML que debes pasar a CSS, y el uso de `<br>` y de `&nbsp;` solo te darán problemas cuando la resolución del dispositivo donde lo esten viendo cambie.  Se tienen que modificar muchísimas cosas para que eso esté un poco decento, lo siento, habria que reescribirlo entero.

Comment: Además, lo has llenado de clases por dentro, que no sabemos lo que son, y por lo tanto quizás eso afectará al aspecto final de lo que modifiquemos. Deberías mostrar tambien tu CSS.  En [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/u9hepvL8/) verás por donde deben ir los tiros (no es una respuesta, es tan solo una muestra de como debería empezar a ser, quitando todo el HTML que has usado para maquetar como si fuera CSS)

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo tu problema mi propuesta seria la siguiente, debes respetar las celdas si quieres dar formato a los datos, no creo que afecte si es que generas los **td** desde un **for** de una consulta o simplemente imprimes en cada celda el dato que quieres pintar.

```html
<table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" width="1000" height="200"><img src="img/iconos/escudo_comprobantes.png" alt=""></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="cabecera" width="1000" height="50">COMPROBANTE DE PERCEPCIONES Y DEDUCCIONES &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Recibo: 317860</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="informacion" valign="top" height="100" width="500">
      <strong>Nombre: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br>
      <strong>CURP: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
      <strong>Puesto: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br>
      <strong>Dependencia: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxx <br>
      <strong>Unidad Admva: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
    </td>

    <td colspan="3" class="informacion" valign="top" height="100" width="500">
      <strong>RFC: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxxxxx<br>
      <strong>Clave de ISSEMYM: &nbsp;</strong>xxxxxx<br>
      <strong>Fecha de pago: &nbsp;</strong>31/10/2022 <br>
      <strong>Periodo de pago: &nbsp;</strong>16/10/2022 al 31/10/2022 <br>
      <strong>Código de Unidad Administrativa: &nbsp;</strong>22600005L <br>
      <strong>Total neto: &nbsp;</strong>1,520.69 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="cabeceras_perded"><strong>Percepciones</strong></td>
    <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="cabeceras_perded"><strong>Deducciones</strong></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Clave</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Concepto</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Importe</td>

    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Clave</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Concepto</td>
    <td colspan="1" cellspacing="0" class="claconimp">Importe</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <!--
        <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="consultaperded" valign="top">
            0202 SUELDOS EVENTUALES (7)1,740.00 <br>
            0325 SUBSIDIO AL EMPLEO 99.46 <br> <br>
            <img class="escudoagua" src="img/iconos/escudo_armas.png" width="500" height="450">
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" cellspacing="0" class="consultaperded" valign="top">
            5540 SERVICIOS DE SALUD 4.625% 121.59 <br>
            5541 SISTEMA SOLIDARIO DE REPARTO 6.1% 160.37 <br>
            5542 CAPITALIZACION INDIVIDUAL 1.4% 36.81 <br>
            <img class="escudoagua" src="img/iconos/escudo_armas.png" width="500" height="450">
        </td>-->
    <!--AGREGUE LOS TD FALTANTES, A MI GUSTO SE DEBEN RESPETAR PARA ASI DAR FORMATO AL DATOS EN CADA CELDA, CON CSS OCULTAS LOS BORDES QUE NO NECESITES-->
    <td style="text-align:center;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;"></td>
    <td colspan="" cellspacing="0" class="consultaclave" valign="top" style="text-align:center;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0px;">
      <p style="text-align: center;">0202</p>

    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0px;"></td>

    <td style="text-align:center;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;">5540</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0px;">SERVICIOS DE SALUD 4.625% </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0px;">121.59</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="totales">Total de percepciones: 1,839.46</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="totales">Total de deducciones: 318.77
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <br> SE REALIZÓ EL ABONO EN LA CUENTA Num.: xxxxxxxxxxx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; EL DÍA: 31/10/2022
      <br><br><br> CONSTITUYE EL RECIBO DE PAGO CORRESPONDIENTE. <br><br><br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Los estilos los puse directamente en las etiquetas **td** pero pásalas a tu CSS, dime si te ayudo.